# How do I load image from firebase database the correct way

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure of -post and -user , under post I have the post information i.e post images, text data , and the uid of the user who posted it. In the user node I have the user info which includes profile image of the user.

Now I'm trying to retrieve posts along with the profile image of the user. I'm able to retrieve the posts but could not load the profile image properly, I tried lots of different ways, the one in the code has 2 indexes when there count becomes equal the tableview is reloaded, this creates conflict and the images are loaded in random fashion even though the count is same. Any idea I could load the images so that they correspond to the right post. I'm new to firebase.

```
func postRetrieve()  {
SVProgressHUD.show()
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timesStamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let post = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    self.userPost.removeAll()

    for (_ , value ) in post {
        if let usersId = value["userID"] as? String  {
            self.usersKey.append(usersId)
            print("here toooo")
            let finalPostToShow = Post()
            if let topicData = value["topic"] as? String,
                let userName = value["creator"] as? String,
                let timeStamp = value["timesStamp"] as? Double

                {
                finalPostToShow.topicData = topicData
                finalPostToShow.usrId = usersId
                finalPostToShow.userName = userName

                self.userPost.append(finalPostToShow)
            }
        }
        print("there are \(self.userPost.count) posts")

    }
     guard self.userPost.count != self.userCred.count else {
            print("loading cells now 01")
            return self.TableViewControllerHome.reloadData()}
}
ref.removeAllObservers()}
```

code for loading profile image called separately:

```
func profileImage() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "timesStamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (dataSnapshots) in
        let usersnap = dataSnapshots.value as? [String : AnyObject]
        self.userCred.removeAll()
        for (_,value) in usersnap! {
            if let userIdKey = value["uid"] as? String {
                let finalUserToShow = user()
                for each in self.usersKey {
                    if each == userIdKey {
                        if let userPhotoImg = value["urlToImage"] as? String{
                            finalUserToShow.ImagePath = userPhotoImg
                            self.userCred.append(finalUserToShow)
                        }
                    }
                    print(finalUserToShow)
                    print("there are   \(self.userCred.count) profile photos")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my firebase Structure :

```
"posts" : {
"-LwxPtjQh6Sq9cMw-XSO" : {
  "attachedUsers" : [ "BtJEpoob3CPR1EN1nFRiUj6uKIX2", "OtipKVdgmyNNR9eGwVFBqyYrvL93", "PV3NEJhepRZQiNHJ7H7KO9aWGy62", "wt4PZb6UUtbeUI2v2SFRZ9hZBNt1" ],
  "content" : "The 2019 Range Rover Autobiography delivers 16 mpg in ",
  "creator" : "Mac",
  "description" : "Rangerover  ",
  "likes" : 0,
  "pathToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neighbors-3a1df.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2%2F-LwxPtjQh6Sq9cMw-XSO.jpeg?alt=media&token=8a87777f-d2c4-4fb9-8c7d-89b5fb0ef042",
  "timesStamp" : 1577283495118,
  "topic" : "Rangerover",
  "userID" : "ssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2",
  "views" : 0,
  "webUrl" : "https://www.landrover.in/index.html"
}
    "-Lx0z-1LlbIhpBFGNIfW" : {
  "attachedUsers" : [ "X0kiMno8EEclwlVvVymNK00wNw52", "OtipKVdgmyNNR9eGwVFBqyYrvL93", "38nPNJujqpeovv558FeFHqB90Qu2", "0NQbltVlx3d3yOwich9IXntyBqD3" ],
  "content" : "The  been",
  "creator" : "Mac",
  "description" : "Cybertruck ",
  "likes" : 0,
  "mainImages" : {
    "-Lx0z0_Nc6FIA_flu_Eq" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neighbors-3a1df.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2%2F-Lx0z0_Nc6FIA_flu_Eq.jpeg?alt=media&token=becde9e1-ca9d-4e98-98ce-e1aa5edeede2",
    "-Lx0z0_T1uxgmU8DCVda" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neighbors-3a1df.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2%2F-Lx0z0_T1uxgmU8DCVda.jpeg?alt=media&token=3b71bca8-8988-481f-994c-41e07fde6972"
  },
  "pathToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neighbors-3a1df.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2%2F-Lx0z-1LlbIhpBFGNIfW.jpeg?alt=media&token=0108e73d-3e34-4137-8729-7e826166d871",
  "timesStamp" : 1577360038766,
  "topic" : "Madness",
  "userID" : "ssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2",
  "views" : 0,
  "webUrl" : ""
},




"users" : {
"0NQbltVlx3d3yOwich9IXntyBqD3" : {
  "dateJoined" : 1541925226084,
  "followers" : {
    "-LR2KlE95CjaV6NLh36e" : "DjyEuBBc3YRGq8lZ1AmDxtUOUNq1",
    "-LRP2W1XXhB1oerC2LJu" : "2EWMigIqM2hObmRQqFgR60T9L5r1",
    "-LTHvpSl8tcVWJs8Gyef" : "9zqI9O8uU1VdeysJ8p0F51AVQG13",
    "-LTTrN2UxHRMkaoZdOJj" : "jeCBp7JvXhhV1hyBCW6pGSdJWxo2",
    "-Lf_gGCB_1nWpfQNIf6d" : "38nPNJujqpeovv558FeFHqB90Qu2",
    "-LtPH3HCtgkT5j2Xq7Hk" : "ssb9HIqEp4SxPuUZSJDUfYYLKPS2"
  },
  "full Name" : "Warren Buffett",
  "uid" : "0NQbltVlx3d3yOwich9IXntyBqD3",
  "urlToImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neighbors-3a1df.appspot.com/o/users%2F0NQbltVlx3d3yOwich9IXntyBqD3.jpg?alt=media&token=673f8326-870e-496c-89ee-3ad9c06693ca"
},
```

function that loads image :

```
class CustomImageView : UIImageView {
func loadImagesWithUrl(from imageUrl : String!)  {
    self.image = nil

    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: imageUrl as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imageUrl)!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, eror) in

        if eror != nil {
            print(eror!)
            return
        }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data : data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: imageUrl as AnyObject)
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

my tableview cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cellData =  TableViewControllerHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! viewControllerHomeCell

   cellData.writingfrom.setTitle(self.userPost[indexPath.row].topicData, for: .normal)
    cellData.profileImage.loadImagesWithUrl(from:self.userCred[indexPath.row].ImagePath)
    cellData.profileName.text = userPost[indexPath.row].userName
    cellData.dateCreated.text = userPost[indexPath.row].dateCreated
    cellData.userID = userPost[indexPath.row].usrId


    return cellData
}
```

Comment: There's no code it the question that loads an image, we need to see that since it's part of the question. Second `ref.removeAllObservers()` is not needed (in this case) as you are not adding an observer; .observeSingleEvent fires once and only once. We really need to see your Firebase structure; please include a snippet of that as TEXT in your question. Lastly, a hint: If you are storing your users in the users node with their uid as the key, you don't need this `if let userIdKey = value["uid"]` as `snapshot.key` will give you the uid of the user.  Update the question and we'll take a look!

Comment: @jay updated buddy

Comment: The most important issue in my comment appears to be overlooked: *There's no code in the question that loads an image*. The included code just assigns a URL to a var in the user class, nothing more. Without that, we won't know what the sequence is for actually loading the image, which is needed to address your question: **How do I load image from firebase database the correct way**

Comment: @jay oh! i ignored that , updated the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer: One is to show example code that demonstrates how to handle the flow of data. The second is to show how to considerably shorten and tighten up your code as there's a lot of extraneous code in the question.

In the question you're working with posts - this answer will be pretty much the same thing; we are going to iterate over our users node and load the users name and profile image into a tableView. The names are stored in Firebase Real Time Database and the images are stored in Firebase Storage (which I strongly recommend using as the API is awesome).

So lets start with a class to store the user name (your post text for example) and then the profile image. Note that the image may be nil in some cases so we need to handle those cases as the tableView refreshes.

```
class UserNameAndImageClass {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    var image: NSImage?

    init(withName: String, andUid: String, andImage: NSImage?) {
        self.name = withName
        self.uid = andUid
        self.image = andImage
    }
}
```

and then a class level var array used as the dataSource for the tableView

```
var userNameAndImageArray = [UserNameAndImageClass]()
```

and then the code that reads in all of the data and populates the dataSouce, and when done, reloads the tableView

```
func fetchUsersAndImages() {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let imagesRef = storageRef.child("images") //where the profile images are stored

    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let lastIndex = snapshot.childrenCount - 1 //how many total child nodes
        var currentIndex = 0 //used to trigger the reload when all data has been read

        //Assign all of the child nodes to an array of DataSnapshots. This keeps them in
        //  order and also maintains each child node as a DataSnapshot making it easier to
        //  access other child data within each node
        let allUsersSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]                                                
        for userSnap in allUsersSnap {
            let uid = userSnap.key
            let name = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
            let profileImageName = "\(uid).png"
            let picRef = imagesRef.child(profileImageName)

            //Firebase Storage code here - insert your own if needed
            picRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
                var aImage: NSImage?
                if let imageData = data { //data could be nil
                    aImage = NSImage(data: imageData)
                }

                let aUser = UserNameAndImageClass(withName: name, andUid: uid, andImage: aImage)
                self.userNameAndImageArray.append(aUser)

                if currentIndex == lastIndex { //if we've loaded all of the users and their images, refresh the UI
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }

                currentIndex += 1
            }
        }
    })
}
```

A few things to note.

In your users node, you're storing the users uid as both the key to the node *as well as* a child node. There's no reason to do that - just store it as the key! If you read that node, you can always access the key with snapshot.key like this

```
let uid = userSnap.key
```

In the section that reads in the picture, note I am using a simple counter that waits until we have read in the last picture before updating the UI. They will reduce flicker. Some would suggest using a Dispatch Group for this task which would work as well.

You do not need to removeAllObservers after using .observeSingleEvent as that only fires once and does not leave an observer.

Last and probably the most important thing: Do not do any heavy lifting in your tableView functions! They should be fast, lightweight with minimalist code. It generally not a good idea to retrieve data from the internet within a cell or tableView function as it will make the app laggy and a poor user experience. Pre-load all of your data to keep the tableview zippy.

Comment: that was a great help ! you showed how to load data more efficiently and precisely from the firebase database and it pretty much addresses the question. But, Suppose a user uploads a post just like in instagram, a seperate "posts" node is created, I can get data easily from the post except the fact that the user's profile image  who  uploaded the post isn't in the "posts" node , rather it is in a separate " users" node. So, how do i get data from two different nodes and show them in one tableviewcell.

Comment: @mac Pretty straightforward. You would get the uid of that user from the post. Then pull the url from the users node and populate as in my answer. In other words, right after `let uid = userSnap.key` then observeSingleEvent on the users node with that uid and within that closure, get the url for the image and then retrieve the image via that url. If the structure gets too deep, you may need to denormalize it but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.